# In even a single-threaded Java application, without a database, are there not sometimes data inconsistency problems?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In many examples that discuss synchronization, it is mentioned something to the effect, "This will work in a single-threaded application, but if multi-threaded..."

I am puzzled because it seems to me possible, although perhaps incredibly unlikely, that even in a single-threaded operation, there can be problems similar to those mentioned in multi-threaded applications.

Say you have an object that has a status field that reflects whether it has been placed into a queue. Pseudo-code would be: object.setStatus(INQUEUE); placeInQueue(object);

Now, if it was somehow possible for the status to be successfully set but the next line of code "silently fail" and the program continue, would we not have a problem wherein we think the object is in the queue but is not? Maybe the idea that we could have a silent failure is false.

But if it is somehow possible for the above problem to occur, how would we make so that the two lines of code either always both executed or both failed?

Answer (score 3):

Logic bugs, that is a flaw in the algorithm, can and regularly do still happen in single threaded applications.  If such a problem exists in a single threaded implementation of the algorithm, then it will only get worse when one tries to make it multi-threaded.

The quote "This will work in a single-threaded application, but if multi-threaded..." was talking about a class of problem that gets introduced by the nature of being concurrent.  For example, if I was in the kitchen baking a cake by myself I would not have to worry about bumping into another chief.  I would however have to still worry about burning my hands on the oven and not bumping my hip on the counter.

The scenario that you describe using a queue, that is backed by disk is another example of parallelism.  Even though our application logic is single threaded, other processes can be writing to disk while our process is working with the queue and so it is possible for the disk to run out of space at no fault of our program.  Handling such problems can become quite involved, the two basic approaches are to either lock out a resource for a period of time or optimistically assume that one will succeed and then handle an error when it fails later.  The example that you gave was an example of the later, only without the error handling.  A silent failure in that scenario can happen in real systems that ignore the problem, and they are broken.

Comment: Chris, if you mean application logic, I am not sure where the bug is. What I am trying to describe is something like this: Say the queue relied upon the file system and the disk became full. I could check for this and if that condition occurred I could explicitly set the status of the object back to "NOTINQUEUE". But what I would like instead for Java to realize that it needed to do this but even as I am typing I realize that Java would have no way of knowing the previous state of the object unless this was explicitly stored and therefore my question was not really a very good one.

Comment: @Jeff what you describe with disks becoming full is also another form of parallelism; other processes are writing to a disk while our application is running.  Java often uses exceptions in this kind of case to communicate that something BAD has happened during disk IO (eg.  ran out of disk space) and the Java libraries handle the concurrency primitives for us relating to the disk IO parts.

Comment: @jeff I have adjusted my answer now that I realize that the example that you gave was also parallel in nature.